# "Лишить полноценной жизни" - можно так написать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Неприятные ощущения способны лишить полноценной жизни.*

Можно так написать?

Answer (score 1):

Как уже было сказано, выражение "лишить полноценной жизни" стилистически неудачно. Короме того, на мой взгляд, логичнее говорить о субъективном ощущении полноты (полноценности) жизни.

**Неприятные ощущения способны лишить ощущения полноты (полноценности) жизни.**

Но если вы хотите говорить о некоей объективно существующей "полноценной жизни", то я бы посоветовал использовать выражения "лишить жизнь полноценности" и "жизнь перестает (может перестать быть) полноценной". Вот два варианта:

**Неприятные ощущения могут лишить (вашу) жизнь полноценности.**

**При появлении неприятных ощущений жизнь может перестать быть полноценной.**

Дополнение.

Возможно, автор хочет составить хлесткую и короткую фразу, подходяшую для рекламной кампании. В таком случае я бы сказал по-другому:

**Неприятные ощущения могут помешать вам радоваться жизни.**

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написала так: Неприятные ощущения несовместимы с полноценной жизнью.

Выражение "лишить жизни" имеет вполне определенный смысл и даже при наличии определения (лишить полноценной жизни) смотрится не лучшим образом.

Answer (score 0):

*Неприятности... способны лишить ощущения полноты жизни.* Это — общий случай.

Если речь о физических ощущениях, то можно употребить слово дискомфорт (или плохое самочувствие).

*Дискомфорт от... способен лишить ощущения полноты жизни.*